# get called gobject finished state

Tags: python, multithreading, gtk, gobject

In a python script i do a gobject call. I need to know, when its finished. are there any possible ways to check this?
Are there Functions or so on to check?

My code is:

```
gobject.idle_add(main.process)

class main:
    def process():
         <-- needs some time to finish -->

next.call.if.finished()
```

I want to start start another object, pending on the first to finish.
I looked through the gobject reference, but i didn't find something necessary. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you can do something like [this](http://www.daa.com.au/pipermail/pygtk/2011-February/019428.html), but in your case, as I understood is simpler and you do not need the result from process(), you just need to use something like

```
main.event.wait() // next.call.if.finished()
```

I already had to use the very same approach from that link, including the necessity of the result, which is a plus.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to start the idle function with a list of the objects you want to process, so instead of waiting for one object to finish and then starting another one, you can  let the idle function re-run itself:

```
def process():
    # process object
    if any_objects_left:
        # set up the next object
        return True
    return False  # remove the idle callback
```